# Force indenting at beginning of theorem environment

Tags: indentation, theorems, ntheorem, parindent

When I do my math homework, I use a theorem environment with custom theorem style via the `amsthm` package to enumerate my problems. I would like the first paragraph inside the theorem environment to be indented. The package `indentfirst` doesn't solve this issue. I know it is a stylistic decision not everyone agrees with, but that's a risk I am willing to take. This is how I have defined the theorem style, I was hoping theres some way I could just add force indent somewhere in there.

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
{\topsep}{\topsep}{\normalfont}{}{\large\bfseries}{\newline}{0em}
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2.}\hfill}
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I vehemently disagree.  What do I disagree with?

1. the `\LARGE` heading;
2. the newline;
3. the indent.

Anyway, here it is how you can do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
  {\topsep}
  {\topsep}
  {\normalfont}
  {}
  {\large\bfseries}
  {\newline}
  {0em}
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2.}\hfill}

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{prob}{%
  \patchcmd{\@begintheorem}{\ignorespaces}{\hspace*{\parindent}\ignorespaces}{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{prob}
\lipsum[1][1-3]

\lipsum[2][1-3]
\end{prob}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot.